# Using a trigger function, how can inserted data on database "A" then get inserted into database "B" (both dbs on same server)?

Tags: postgresql, dblink, foreign-data-wrapper

This is what I've created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION contractor.insert_into_iso()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_connect('dbname=ISO');
    PERFORM dblink_exec('INSERT INTO public.trades (market, trader, strategy, pricedate, hour, nodename, sinknode, bidvolume, bidprice, utc) VALUES (''' || NEW.market || ''', ''' || NEW.trader || ''', ' || NEW.strategy || ', ''' || NEW.pricedate || ''', ' || NEW.hour || ', ''' || NEW.nodename || ''', ''' || NEW.sinknode || ''', ' || NEW.bidvolume || ', ' || NEW.bidprice || ', ' || NEW.utc || ')');
    PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_into_iso_trig
AFTER INSERT ON contractor.trades
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_into_iso();
```

But when I insert data into contractor.trades, nothing gets inserted into public.trades on the second db named ISO.

Comment: I would look at the logs for both Postgres servers to see if there is relevant information.